# Storing information in an SP Online App

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have been able to find nothing about storing information in a **SharePoint Online** app. I need to be able to pull down a bunch of information from the search API, store it, and be able to access it when the app is revisited. Ideally this would be shared between all users. Grabbing this info from the API on-demand is too slow for what I am trying to do.

EDIT: Initial idea is to create a list in my solution and deploy it with my app. I can create columns in it as needed and query it... unsure if this is going to be any faster than going to search.

Comment: What 'search API' are you referring to?  SharePoint APIs?

Comment: @tyshock Yes, the [SharePoint Search REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using autohosted app model, You should be able to cache the search result on serverside as well as client side.

In the SharePoint hosted model, you can use client side caching/storage options to store search result. Here are few html5 options to consider apart for using cookies:
1. [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)
2. [Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)
3. IndexedDB:_http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/
4. File API:_http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html